# Windows Vista language text service problem

Tags: windows-vista

I'm using English version of Vista and having problems with using programs that display Russian characters somewhere. For example dictionaries doesn't work for me, since they display Russian character. Also I see just "magic" characters in text editor (notepad) when open a Russian text file. I tried to change whole Vista Interface language to Russian, but it still didn't solve the problem.

I CAN read any web page from browser, that's not a problem. Also adding "Russian" in "Text Services and Input Languages" doesn't solve this problem.

**Does anyone know how to solve this?**

Thanks.

My System: 32-bit Windows Vista Home Premium - SP2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending whole day on this issue I was finally able to solve it.
I just needed to change language for non-Unicode applications to Russian. I never knew about this property :). I hope my answer will be helpful to someone.